# What happens with the Items in Corvo Bianco when starting a New Game+

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine

In the Blood and Wine DLC you become the owner of the vineyard Corvo Bianco.

There you have armor and weapon stands where you can put some of your gear on display.

When starting a New Game+ do you keep the stuff you put on display, or do you have to pick it up before starting a new game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got far enough on a play through to check this. Armor and weapons on stands at Corvo Bianco do **not** appear in the stash when you do a New Game+. So you need to pick them up or put them in the stash before starting the new game.